# Can add new in app purchase for my app after update

Tags: iphone, ios4, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I made update for my app and added an in app purchases. I submited new binary and in app purchases and everyting is Ok. Can i add new in app purchase for this binary or i need to create a new update(new version of my app) and submit it with my new in app purchase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add new in-app purchases without submitting your app again.

As long as your app is setup to check for new purchases remotely, and show them accordingly in your app, and not depend on you manually adding them to your app you should be alright.

Comment: I am searching for days already to find an answer to this question in Apple manuals. Do you know which Apple manuals to look at to verify your answer? Thanks!